# Expandable list view in Scroll view not showing all header titles

Tags: java, android

So, created Expandable List View today, implemented it in Scroll view, but I can only see one header (title) from parent_layout. You'll see it in first picture:

[image: slika1]

but there are 4 titles.

Second problem, whey I expand the list, other titles appear, but when all are expanded except the last one, you can't see the title:

[image: slika2]

You can see it one picture above, at the bottom of it.

Third problem, how can I reposition the arrow to the right and change the color? That one arrow circled in previous picture.

Here's my code:

Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by dario on 10.02.16..
 */
public class Adapter531 extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<String> header_titles;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> child_titles;
    private Context ctx;
    Adapter531(Context ctx, List<String> header_titles, HashMap<String, List<String>> child_titles){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.child_titles = child_titles;
        this.header_titles = header_titles;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return header_titles.size();
        //vraća kolko parenta imaš
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).size();
        //vraća broj child itema u svakom headingu
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return header_titles.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String title = (String)this.getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_531_layout, null);
        }
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading_item);
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        textView.setText(title);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String title = (String)this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_531_layout, null);
        }

        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_item);
        textView.setText(title);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Java file

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ProgramiPowerlifting531 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_programi_powerlifting531);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_listview531);
        List<String> Headings = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> L1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> L2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> L3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> L4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashMap<String, List<String>> ChildList = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        String heading_items[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.header_titles);
        String l1[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.h1_items);
        String l2[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.h2_items);
        String l3[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.h3_items);
        String l4[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.h4_items);

        for (String title : heading_items) {
            Headings.add(title);
        }
        for (String title : l1) {
            L1.add(title);
        }
        for (String title : l2) {
            L2.add(title);
        }
        for (String title : l3) {
            L3.add(title);
        }
        for (String title : l4) {
            L4.add(title);
        }

        ChildList.put(Headings.get(0), L1);
        ChildList.put(Headings.get(1), L2);
        ChildList.put(Headings.get(2), L3);
        ChildList.put(Headings.get(3), L4);
        Adapter531 adapter531 = new Adapter531(this, Headings, ChildList);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter531);
        expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, long id) {
                setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
        private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView,
        int group) {
            ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
            int totalHeight = 0;
            int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                    View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
                View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
                groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

                if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                        || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                        View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                                listView);
                        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

                        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

                    }
                }
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            int height = totalHeight
                    + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
            if (height < 10)
                height = 200;
            params.height = height;
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();

        }

    }
```

XML of activity

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/exp_listview531"
        >

    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Parent XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Prvo"
        android:id="@+id/heading_item"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Child XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Jel radi?"
        android:id="@+id/child_item"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#424242" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Strings

```
<string-array name="header_titles">
    <item>\t\t\t\t\tPonedjeljak - čučanj</item>
    <item>\t\t\t\t\tUtorak - potisak s klupe</item>
    <item>\t\t\t\t\tČetvrtak - mrtvo dizanje</item>
    <item>\t\t\t\t\tPetak - potisak iznad glave</item>

</string-array>

<string-array name="h1_items">
    <item>1. Čučanj, 3 serije</item>
    <item>\t\t1. tjedan - 3 x 5 (65, 75, 85% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t2. tjedan - 3 x 3 (70, 80, 90% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t3. tjedan - 3 x 5/3/1 (75, 85, 95% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t4. tjedan - 3 x 5 (40, 50, 60%)</item>
    <item>2. Nožna ekstenzija, 5 x 10</item>
    <item>3. Nožna fleksija, 5 x 10</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="h2_items">
    <item>1. Potisak s klupe, 3 serije</item>
    <item>\t\t1. tjedan - 3 x 5 (65, 75, 85% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t2. tjedan - 3 x 3 (70, 80, 90% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t3. tjedan - 3 x 5/3/1 (75, 85, 95% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t4. tjedan - 3 x 5 (40, 50, 60%)</item>
    <item>2. Potisak s kose klupe, 5 x 10</item>
    <item>3. Razvlačenje kablovima, 5 x 10</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="h3_items">
    <item>1. Mrtvo dizanje, 3 serije</item>
    <item>\t\t1. tjedan - 3 x 5 (65, 75, 85% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t2. tjedan - 3 x 3 (70, 80, 90% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t3. tjedan - 3 x 5/3/1 (75, 85, 95% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t4. tjedan - 3 x 5 (40, 50, 60%)</item>
    <item>2. Veslanje u pretklonu, 5 x 10</item>
    <item>3. Povlačenja na lat mašini, 5 x 10</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="h4_items">
    <item>1. Potisak iznad glave, 3 serije</item>
    <item>\t\t1. tjedan - 3 x 5 (65, 75, 85% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t2. tjedan - 3 x 3 (70, 80, 90% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t3. tjedan - 3 x 5/3/1 (75, 85, 95% 1RM)</item>
    <item>\t\t4. tjedan - 3 x 5 (40, 50, 60%)</item>
    <item>2. Francuski potisak, 5 x 10</item>
    <item>3. Pregib za biceps, 5 x 10</item>
</string-array>
```

activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.ProgramiPowerlifting531"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_programi_powerlifting531"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/Osnivac"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout14"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Osnivač programa"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Osnivač ovog programa je Jim Wendler, powerlifter koji je na vrhu svoje karijere podigao 455kg u čučnju pa mu očito možemo vjerovati da zna o čemu govori i da program djeluje."
            android:id="@+id/textViewOsnivačPrograma"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:background="@mipmap/slika_programi_pl_531_jimwendler"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/Osnove"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout15"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout14"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="5/3/1 osnove"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="abc "
            android:id="@+id/textView531osnove" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/Izgled"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="2.90"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout15"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout16"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Izgled programa"
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="U osnovi program izgleda ovako:\n\n
1.  tjedan: 3 x 5\n
2.  tjedan: 3 x 3\n
3.  tjedan: 3 x 5,3,1\n
4.  tjedan: deload (tjedan za oporavak)\n\n
* prvi broj označava broj serija, a drugi označava broj ponavljanja\n\n
Postoci svakog tjedna izgledaju ovako:\n
"
            android:id="@+id/textViewIzgledPrograma" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@mipmap/tablica_531_postoci"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="\n* + označava da se od osobe očekuje da prekorači zadan broj ponavljanja
\n\nNakon završena 4 tjedan potrebno je na sadašnji maksimum (u našem primjeru 180kg) dodati 5lbs (2.5kg) na potisak s klupe i potisak iznad glave te 10lbs (4.5kg) na čučanj i mrtvo dizanje. Vrlo je važno da ne nadodajete više od propisanog na kraju ciklusa jer će to nakon nekoliko mjeseci dovesti do stagnacije napretka.
"
            android:id="@+id/textViewIzgledProgramaNastavak" />


    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/DodatneVjezbe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="2.90"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout16"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout17"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Dodatne vježbe"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Svrha dodatnih vježbi je prebroditi slabosti i stvoriti dodatnu ravnotežu. Za svaki od dana potrebno je raditi nekoliko dodatnih vježbi. One variraju kod svakog pojedinca.
\n\nNeki od primjera:
\n\nDodatne vježbe za čučanj: prednji čučanj, dobro jutro, iskoraci s bučicama ili šipkom, nožna fleksija, nožna ekstenzija, ekstenzija za leđa.
\n\nDodatne vježbe za potisak s klupe: potisak s kose klupe šipkom ili bučicama, razvlačenje bučicama ili kablovima, propadanja.
\n\nDodatne vježbe za mrtvo dizanje: rumunjsko mrtvo dizanje, obrnuta hiperekstenzija, ekstenzija za leđa.
\n\nDodatne vježbe za potisak iznad glave: sljeganje ramenima, pregib za biceps bučicama ili šipkom, francuski potisak, hammer pregib, obrnuti pregib šipkom.
"
            android:id="@+id/textView11" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/PrimjerPrograma"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="2.90"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout17"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout18"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Primjer programa"
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/exp_listview531"
                >

            </ExpandableListView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/DodatneNapomene"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="2.90"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout18"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Dodatne napomene"
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Pročitajte kako se pravilno izvode vježbe – u našoj aplikaciji detaljno je objašnjeno kako se svaka od vježbi s kojom ćete se susresti u ovom programu izvodi.
\n\nForma iznad svega – dobra forma omogućit će podizanje većih tereta i čuva zdravlje osobe čiji je cilj da postane što jaća, ne da postane invalid.
\n\nDugoročni plan – ovaj program testiran je na tisućama ljudi diljem svijeta i zasigurno funkcionira te je stvoren za dugoročno korištenje.

\n\nOdmor - odmori između serija kod glavnih vježbi traju od 3 do 5 minuta, ovisno koliko je osobi potrebno da može ponovno dizati kilaže koje su joj blizu maksimuma. Za dodatne vježbe 2 minute. Ako osoba nije spremna nakon dvije minute treba smanjiti kilažu.
\n\nZagrijavanje - za uspješno odrađen trening potrebno je razgibati se, povisiti brzinu rada srca i odraditi nekoliko serija glavnih vježbi s manjim kilažama.
"
            android:id="@+id/textView14" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why do you put the `ListView` in a `ScrollView`? I don't know if this causes your problem, but it is unnecessary since `ListView` already implements scrolling.

Comment: Because I don't want all the text to appear for each title, I won't it to appear only when the user clicks on it

Comment: That's why you have an **expandable** list. This still doesn't require a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Also, it will help if you post the appropriate XML layout files.

Comment: XML files added. I need scroll view because i have a lot of text in that activity, not just list view

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see a `ScrollView` in any of your XML files. Of course, I'm probably getting hung up on an irrelevant detail.

Comment: Ok, that file is Up now, but it's pretty long. So do you know how to fix my problems?

Comment: It seems to me that your `activity.xml` is too complex. I highly recommend that you find ways to split this into separate views using a combination of separate `Fragment`s and `Activity`s. You should even consider using a `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android suggests not to use ListViews etc inside ScrollViews as they already have the scroll features themselves, but there are times when you need such a feature ( as yours)...so you must calculate your Expandable or ListViews height before rendering is done for the scroll...

[here](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/expandable-listview-inside-scrollview/) is how youll do it.

For your second problem changing indicator to the right..
you can modify the layout in your adapter and use custom image and hide and show it based on click eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706231/put-on-the-right-the-indicator-of-an-expandablelistview-in-android)
or you can calculate and reposition it using the inhouse method

```
setIndicatorBounds(int, int)
setIndicatorBoundsRelative(int, int)
```

eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528542/how-to-change-expandablelistview-group-indicator-position)

Comment: NEVER MIND, found it. But that only solves one problem. Do you know why does it show only one title and how can I reposition the arrow?

Comment: 1/3 not bad :p, edited so that atleast you can reposition.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the problem with not all titles showing:
Set height of `ExpandableListView` to something specific like `200dp`, not `wrap_content, fill_parent or match_parent`