# Only one expandable list view displays at page load

Tags: java, android, android-layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am using two different `ExpandableListViews` in my fragment inside a scroll view, one right below the other.

The problem is that only one `ExpandableListView` heading is displayed when the activity is called. Please refer the image below:

[image]

Also, when I click the expandable list view, the list view expands and the other `ExpandableListView` also displays. Refer the image below:

[image]

I want the both the Expandable list views to display when the activity gets called for the first time.

This is my xml:

```
<ExpandableListView
      android:id="@+id/exLInTheMoodFor"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:scrollbars="none"
      android:groupIndicator="@null"
      android:layout_below="@+id/lblInTheMoodFor"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

And this is the java code for defining and initializing the Expandable list view and setting height:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cafes_more_fragment, container, false);

        final ExpandListChild1 items = new ExpandListChild1();

        exLInTheMoodFor = (ExpandableListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exLInTheMoodFor);
        ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
        ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapterProduct(activity, ExpListItems);
        exLInTheMoodFor.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);

        exLInTheMoodFor.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, long l) {
                setListViewHeight(exLInTheMoodFor, i);
                return false;
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    //for set height show method in expnadable list view
    private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView, int group) {
        android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
            View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
            groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

            totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                    || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                    View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                            listView);
                    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
                }
            }
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        int height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
        if (height < 10)
            height = 200;
        params.height = height;
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your full xml layout code? OR just answer this: did you use any scrollview in your xml layout?

Comment: @ImtiazAbir  Yes I did!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding all groups in the list

```
for(int i=0; i < myAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
mexpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
```

if Expanding one item in the list

```
mexpandableListView.expandGroup(0);
```

One item Expanding and balance item compressed

```
mexpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGroupExpand(int i) {
                        ExpandableAdapter myAdapter= (ExpandableHomeworkAdapter) mexpandableListView.getExpandableListAdapter();
                        if (myAdapter== null){
                            return;
                        }
                        for (int k=0;k<myAdapter.getGroupCount();k++){
                            if (k!=i){
                                mexpandableListView.collapseGroup(k);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: it working for me but am using one Expandable listview , if you don't mine can you check it one expandable listview .

Comment: I am using this inside a scrollview.

Comment: no need scrollview  for expandable listview, create another activity and do one expandable listview and implement this method and check it , then if it is working problem is using two expandable listview using inside scrollview..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using listview/expandablelistview inside scrollview. Generally this combination causes the visibility issue of listview existing inside the scrollview. Full explanation can be found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35324531/5590249) answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18411494/android-listview-show-only-one-item) link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view) link should also be helpful for solving your problem. I hope this helps.